# sql- query to view all hostname of URLs with their count

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table with column containing many URLs, I want to get all the distinct hostnames with their count

```
column_links
----------
http://abcd.com/efgh/ijk/lmn
http://qwer.com/qwqwq/qwq/wdsd
http://abcd.com/jhksdh/khsdh/khd
http://abcd.com/dsfsdh/khsdh/dsfsdf
http://qwer.com/ihwlidhw/ddsd/wqeqe
```

should produce

```
╔════╦══════════════════╦══════╗
║    ║  hostnames       ║  2   ║
╠════╬══════════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ http://abcd.com  ║  3   ║
║  2 ║ http://qwer.com  ║  2   ║
╚════╩══════════════════╩══════╝
```

I can't make up a query, i am not good at regex

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are good at regular expressions. MySQL can't use them in `SELECT` clauses anyhow.  You may want to investigate  the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Think Ahead -- You should have split the two parts of the URLs into two columns _as you inserted them_.  Things (other than DATETIME) are much easier put back together than to take apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SUBSTRING_INDEX() is a string function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) that does what you need to do in editing URLs into hostnames.  This query should do the trick for you. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/940481/1/0)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_links,'/',3) host,
       COUNT(*) number
  FROM links
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_links,'/',3)
```

Comment: Worked but slow